# Lubuntu 12.04 installation trouble

Tags: 12.04, installation, lubuntu

I have i problem! I can't install the Lubuntu 12.04 on my old pc. I only get to the point where I have entered all the needed information (hard drive, username, password etc). When the installation wizard is starting to copy files from the cd to the hard drive, I get after about one minute a blank sreen with only themouse cursor! I can move the mouse cursor but the whole procegure is stoped! Nothing happens after that!

My PC:
Compaq Pressario 7000
Pentium III 933 MHz
768 MB RAM

Any idea how to solve it??

Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you installing it alongside other OS (perhaps Windows), erasing and installing over old Linux, or did you create new partitions for it .. ??

Answer (score 2):

Use an Alternate CD to install the system, or switch to console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> to  <kbd>F6</kbd> to see a terminal with eventual error messages.

Comment: yeah I have seen the lubuntu installer fail like this 10's of times

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me....

1. Try pressing F6 at the 1st instalation screen and select the "nomodeset" option.
2. Then hit ESC after selecting "nomodeset" from the options, This will allow you to edit the kernel options directly. Type "xforcevesa" before the "--"
3. Hit enter to start the installation